# Print Two Pages on One Page

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has around three pages of information and four columns per page.

To save printing I would like to print the second page of four columns on the first page of four columns with say one column of "blank whitespace" to separate the two.

Comment: You could setup a 2nd sheet for printing with references to 1st sheet.  =Sheet1!A1 for rows 1-40, then 6 columns over, =indirect("Sheet1!A"&row()+40)  if you were getting 40 rows on your print sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most complete yet simplified version of getting a print job to work. This is a fairly simple code in that it expects data to be in Columns A:D and Rows 1:80, but can be tailored to suite more complicated needs.

It creates a `Temp` sheet, copies the data, prints and then deletes the `Temp` sheet.

```
Sub Print_Test()

With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Temp"
        Set tempsh = Sheets("Temp")
End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D40").Copy Destination:=tempsh.Range("A1")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A41:D80").Copy Destination:=tempsh.Range("F1")

With Application
 With .ActiveSheet
 With .PageSetup
 End With
 End With
  .Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
End With


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Worksheets("Temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```